# Determining if a function is continuous

Tags: calculus

\begin{array}{l}
f(x)=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{|x|}x & \text{if $x\ne 0$}\\
0 & \text{if $x = 0$}
\end{cases}\\
g(x)=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\sin x} x & \text{if $x\ne 0$}\\
1 & \text{if $x = 0$}
\end{cases}\\
h(x)=\begin{cases}
x^2+2x & \text{if $x\ge 1$}\\
1+2\cos(x-1) & \text{if $x < 1$}
\end{cases}
\end{array}

I know that a function is continuous at $a$ iff
$$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = f(a).$$

But I can't really figure out when a function is continuous *everywhere*.

Can you tell me the way I should approach this, *without* plotting a graph?

For the first one, I know that the form of the plot of the function looks like this:

---------.-----------

Comment: A function is continuous everywhere if it is continuous at $a$ for all $a$.

Comment: well you can start of by drawing graphs, they say if you can draw the graph without having to take the pen off the paper thats a good indication but by no means sufficient, also note if a function is differentiable at a point it is also continuous there. Usually you can show a function is continuous for a region as its usually a compoisition of continouus functions, however at certain points, you need to determine continuity there are several ways: 1)epilson-delta way 2)via limits etc.

Comment: If two functions $f$ and $g$ are continuous in D. Then $f+g$ , $f-g$, $cf$, $cg$,$fg$, and $f/g$ are continuous in D (For the last case the continuity is for every point were $g$ is non-zero), here $c$ is a real constant. This will help you prove continuity at every other point. As it is easy to prove the functions $x$ , $\sin x$ and$\cos x$ (the ones to be used in your questions) are contininous in $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuity of a function is defined if it is continuous in the entire domain , such that for every $a$ , $f(a) = \lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x) $ should exist . Now for $g(x)$ you can verify that the function will be continuous at every point for $a \ne 0$ ie you can verify that if $a\ne0$ then $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} \frac{sin(x)}{x} = \frac{sin(a)}{a}$ which is equal to $f(a) = \frac{sin(a)}{a}$ . But the only point where one can be suspicious about the function being discontinous is at the point $a=0$ because there the denominator will become $0$ . So we will evaluate the limit as $x \rightarrow 0$ which for this case is equal to $1$ and the value of $f(x)$ at this point ie $f(0) = 1$ is given to be $1$ , hence the function is continuous everywhere .

Answer (score 0):

The first one is not continuous, because $\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+} f(x) = 1$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow0^-} = -1$ but $f(0) = 0$.

The second one is continuous. The only limit point you need to check is $x=0$ because $\sin(x) / x$ is obviously continuous everywhere else. And yes, $\lim_{x\rightarrow0} \sin(x)/x = 1$.

The third one is also continuous. Again, the only point you have to check is the junction at $x=1$. $f(1) = \lim_{x\rightarrow1^+} f(x) = 3$ because $x^2 + 2x$ is continuous. So you need to check $\lim_{x\rightarrow1^-} 1 + 2\cos(x-1) = 1 + 2\cos(1-1) = 3$.

Comment: For the first the lateral limits are different. For $x \to 0^-$ you have $f(x) \to -1$, whereas for $x \to 0^+$ you have $f(x) = 1$. Discontinuous, yes, but this is important.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that. I will fix it.